# Where are cshtml files and Controllers in Umbraco with Mvc?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I've just installed Umbraco 6.1.6 making sure to have this setting in the \Config\umbracoSettings.config file before starting the install process.

```
<defaultRenderingEngine>Mvc</defaultRenderingEngine>
```

The site has installed fine, and runs fine, but the site is still full of .aspx and .ascx files. What gives? Shouldn't it have created .cshtml files for views, layouts and Controllers and stuff?

Or have I misunderstood and that is up to the user to put in?

Cheers,

-- Lee

Answer (score 1):

Some part of umbraco will still use UserControls.

Try making a new documentType, that will create a view that matches that doctype

You can overrule the default Controller by creating a Controller with the same name.
Remember to inhert from.

```
public class NameOfTheDocTypeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
```